# Python - Shift Data to a different ROW

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am kind of new to data frames and been trying to find a solution to shift data in specific columns to another row if `ID` and `CODE` matches.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['123', '123', '123', '154', '167', '167'], 
                   'NAME': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Charlie'],
                   'CODE': ['1001', '1001', '1011', '1002', 'A0101', 'A0101'],
                   'TAG1': ['A123', 'B123', 'K123', 'D123', 'E123', 'G123'],
                   'TAG2': [ np.NaN, 'C123', 'L123', np.NaN, 'F123', 'H123'],
                   'TAG3': [ np.NaN, 'M123', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]})
```

```
    ID    NAME      CODE    TAG1    TAG2    TAG3
0   123   Adam      1001    A123    NaN     NaN
1   123   Adam      1001    B123    C123    M123
2   123   Adam      1011    K123    L123    NaN
3   154   Bob       1002    D123    NaN     NaN
4   167   Charlie   A0101   E123    F123    NaN
5   167   Charlie   A0101   G123    H123    NaN
```

So above I have added the code which depicts the initial data frame, now we can see that `ID='123'` has two rows with the same codes and the values in `'TAG'` columns vary, I would like to shift the `'TAG'` data in the second row to the first row after `'TAG1'` or in `'TAG1'` if it is empty and delete the second row completely. It should be the same for `ID='167'`.

Below is another code with a sample data frame I have added manually which depicts the final result, any suggestions would be great. I tried one thing, it exactly did not work the way I wanted it to.

```
    df_result = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['123', '123', '154', '167'], 
                   'NAME': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Bob', 'Charlie',],
                   'CODE': ['1001', '1011', '1002', 'A0101'],
                   'TAG1': ['A123', 'K123', 'D123', 'E123'],
                   'TAG2': ['B123', 'L123', np.NaN, 'F123'],
                   'TAG3': ['C123', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'G123'],
                   'TAG4': ['M123', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'H123']})
```

```
     ID     NAME    CODE    TAG1    TAG2    TAG3    TAG4
0    123    Adam    1001    A123    B123    C123    M123
1    123    Adam    1011    K123    L123    NaN     NaN
2    154    Bob     1002    D123    NaN     NaN     NaN
3    167    Charlie A0101   E123    F123    G123    H123
```

The code that I have tried is below to kind of get the result. But it did not get exactly the output I wanted

```
df2=pd.pivot_table(test_shift, index=['ID', 'NAME', 'CODE'], 
columns=test_shift.groupby(['ID', 'CODE']).cumcount().add(1),
values=['TAG1'], aggfunc='sum')
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc7bp.png)

NOTE: Sorry for the bad posting the first time, I tried adding the dataframe as code to help you visually. But I `'FAILED'`. I will try to learn that over the coming days and be a better member of `'Stack Overflow`.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples   This would help greatly if you created  your  input dataframes like this instead of using pictures.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @ScottBoston and wwii. Thank you for the links, I did check them and they do help me in posting my questions perfectly. But sorry that I couldn't do that yet, I will keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: @wwii Thank you for the suggestion, I tried and posted the code. But I was unable to add the data frame onto the post. I will try that once again over the next few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one-way:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.stack().to_frame(name='val')
    x = x.assign(tags='Tag'+x["val"].notna().cumsum().astype(str))
    x = (x.reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
          .set_index('tags', append=True)['val'].unstack())
    return x

df_out = (df.set_index(['ID', 'NAME','CODE'])
           .groupby(level=[0,1,2], as_index=False).apply(f)
           .reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1))

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    ID     NAME   CODE  Tag1  Tag2  Tag3  Tag4
0  123     Adam   1001  A123  B123  C123  M123
1  123     Adam   1011  K123  L123   NaN   NaN
2  154      Bob   1002  D123   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  167  Charlie  A0101  E123  F123  G123  H123
```

Comment: @Scott_Boston, I was able to run the code and it worked as expected for the test data, I have run it against my orginal dataset and there was a small error which I wasn't able to fix and didn't exactly get back to it. I tried it again and it gave me a Key Error, so mostly it is respective to changing the "Column" declaration in the code. I will get it fixed.

Comment: @stubbledweb1995 Key Error is either column name doesn't exists or row index label doesn't exists.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. The total number of new TAG columns that were created totaled out to be 961. I would like to know if there is a way to limit the TAG columns to 9. Like Tag1, Tag 2, ... Tag 9. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

An approach with `pd.wide_to_long` for flattening the `TAGS` and then mapping the index as per the group of `ID` and `CODE` , then unstacking and joining the de-duplicated rows from `ID`,`NAME` and `CODE`

```
u = pd.wide_to_long(df.filter(like='TAG').reset_index(),'TAG','index','j').dropna()

idx = u.index.get_level_values(0).map(df.groupby(['ID','CODE']).ngroup()) 

u = u.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((idx,u.groupby(idx).cumcount()+1))).unstack()
u.columns = u.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)

out = df[['ID','NAME','CODE']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).join(u)
```

---

```
print(out)

    ID     NAME   CODE  TAG1  TAG2  TAG3  TAG4
0  123     Adam   1001  A123  B123  C123  M123
1  123     Adam   1011  K123  L123   NaN   NaN
2  154      Bob   1002  D123   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  167  Charlie  A0101  E123  F123  G123  H123
```

Comment: I did run the code and it went without any hitch. I was able to modify all the required fields accordingly. I got a IndexError at the 3rd line and I am trying to figure out the root cause.